# Count If in a User Defined range

Tags: excel, vba

I want a CountIf Formula in which JV_Rng (workbook 1 range) is the range and 9th column (and r row) of GL_Sheet (workbook 2) is the criteria. Upon running the code I receive error 1004 (application or object defined error)
The error is possibly due to my inability to include the JV_Rng in the Count If Formula. The whole code is as follows

```
'Filtering Range
Dim GL_Code As Single, GL_Rng As range, GL_LR As Long
Dim GL_Sheet As Worksheet
Set GL_Sheet = Workbooks("Deodar GL activities.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
GL_LR = GL_Sheet.range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
GL_Code = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter GL code", Title:="Generate GL", Type:=1)
Set GL_Rng = GL_Sheet.range("A4:R" & GL_LR).CurrentRegion.Offset(3, 0)
GL_Rng.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=GL_Code

'Shift Rng into new sheet
Dim Tgt_Book As Workbook
Set Tgt_Book = Workbooks.Add
Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = Tgt_Book.Worksheets.Add
......

'Shift JV of that Code
Dim r As Long, JV_Rng As range
Set JV_Rng = tgt.range("J6:R" & GL_LR).Offset(5, 0)
For r = 5 To GL_LR
GL_Sheet.range("S" & r).Formula = "=COUNTIF(tgt.Range(JV_rng),R[r]C[9])"
Next r
```

The code is working successfully except for this part

```
GL_Sheet.range("S" & r).Formula = "=COUNTIF(tgt.Range(JV_rng),R[r]C[9])"
```

Comment: `.Formula` requires `A1` notation; you're using `R1C1` notation... and you've got a variable inside the quotes.

Comment: Is there anyway to refer to that variable inside quotes?

Comment: Don't. Use `&` to concatenate, drop the `tgt.Range`, and use `JV_rng.Address`. You still have to fix the `R[r]C[9]` portion too.

Comment: If it helps, `Debug.Print` the formula - the result in the Immediate Window should be the same as if you typed it manually in the cell.

Comment: Hi.  Stack Overflow is working on a new feature [Your Reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction?cb=1).   If you have found your answer, please click on the ICON under voting.  Long-Life to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, replace:

```
For r = 5 To GL_LR
GL_Sheet.range("S" & r).Formula = "=COUNTIF(tgt.Range(JV_rng),R[r]C[9])"
Next r
```

with

```
tgt.range("S5:S" & GL_LR).Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & JV_Rng.Address(external:=True) &  ", I5)"
```

No iteration needed.

In above code line I tried to convert your `R[r]C[9]` in A1 notation. Would you like counting I:I column cells values in S:S column? Otherwise, your formula was not targeting the correct ranges...

Comment: Hey thanks for your response
Yup there seems to be an issue with the range being targeted
Your suggested code is working correctly, only problem being that JV_Rng.Address pertains a workbook ("tgt"). I want to fill values in another workbook ("GL_Sheet"). With the code below although the value is being recorded in "GL_Sheet", it takes JV_Rng.Address as address of GL_Sheet instead of tgt (although I have defined it to do otherwise)
 
The codes are:
 
'   Set JV_Rng = tgt.range("J1:J" & JV_LR).Offset(5, 0)

'  GL_Sheet.range("S5").Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & JV_Rng.Address & ", I5)"

Comment: @Naqi Kazmi I did not do anything else then trying to transform your code, with your ranges declarations in something able to work... So, you need the `JV_Rng` range address sheet name inclusive? If yes, I adapted the code line to return its address in this way.

Comment: @Naqi Kazmi: Glad I could help!